# How to find the hour and text place from Google places api?

Tags: android, google-places-api

I need to take a details places plike PhoneNumber,WebsiteUri and etc, I read this: https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/place-details but I don't find the methods: hour and text place, like this pic.

[image]

this is the code:

```
public class PlaceDetails {
String id;
CharSequence name;
LatLngBounds hour;
CharSequence address;
List<Integer> placeTypes;
CharSequence phoneNumber;
Uri websiteUri;

public LatLngBounds getHour() {
    return hour;
}

public void setHour(LatLngBounds hour) {
    this.hour = hour;
}

public Uri getWebsiteUri() {
    return websiteUri;
}

public void setWebsiteUri(Uri websiteUri) {
    this.websiteUri = websiteUri;
}

public CharSequence getPhoneNumber() {
    return phoneNumber;
}

public void setPhoneNumber(CharSequence phoneNumber) {
    this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
}

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public CharSequence getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(CharSequence name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public CharSequence getAddress() {
    return address;
}

public void setAddress(CharSequence address) {
    this.address = address;
}

public List<Integer> getPlaceTypes() {
    return placeTypes;
}

public void setPlaceTypes(List<Integer> placeTypes) {
    this.placeTypes = placeTypes;
}


private void setPlaceDetails(PlaceBuffer places) {
    Log.i(TAG, "setPlaces to PlaceDetails");

    if(places.get(0).getAddress() != null){
        placeDetails.setAddress(places.get(0).getAddress());
    }
    if(places.get(0).getId() != null){
        placeDetails.setId(places.get(0).getId());
    }
    if(places.get(0).getName() != null){
        placeDetails.setName(places.get(0).getName());
    }
    if(places.get(0).getPhoneNumber() != null){
        placeDetails.setPhoneNumber(places.get(0).getPhoneNumber());
    }
    if(places.get(0).getPlaceTypes() != null){
        placeDetails.setPlaceTypes(places.get(0).getPlaceTypes());
    }

    if(places.get(0).getHour() != null) {
        placeDetails.setHour(places.get(0).getHour());
    }

    if(places.get(0).getPlaceTypes() != null){
        placeDetails.setWebsiteUri(places.get(0).getWebsiteUri());
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Please add the code for what you've tried so far.

Comment: I add the cod and I need to set Hour Opening from google places details api.

Comment: someone can  help me pleas?